# How to communicate in line mode rather than a character per time with Node in git bash

Tags: javascript, windows, telnet, git-bash

I have been using git bash in Windows 10, to try out the telnet command. When communicating between different clients(terminal windows), it is found that only a single character is sent.

```
let net = require('net');

let chatServer = net.createServer();
let clientList = [];

const broadcast = (message, client) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < clientList.length; ++i) {
    if (client !== clientList[i]) {
      clientList[i].write(client.name + ": " + message + "\n");
    }
  }
};

chatServer.on('connection', (client) => {
  client.name = client.remoteAddress + ':' + client.remotePort;
  client.write("Hi, " + client.name + "!\n");
  clientList.push(client);
  client.on('data', (data) => {
    broadcast(data, client);
  });
});

chatServer.listen(9000);
```

Above is my source code with Node in javascript. The response of message "abc" is like below.

```
Hi, ::ffff:127.0.0.1:51278!
                           ::ffff:127.0.0.1:51285: a
                                                    ::ffff:127.0.0.1:51285: b

::ffff:127.0.0.1:51285: c
```

I just wanted to have this communication goes under line by line mode, rather than sending a single character per key stroke. Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like you need to add `\r` before `\n` to get it to print correctly on Windows.

Comment: [Read more about Telnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet), especially [the specifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet#Related_RFCs). You might need to *negotiate* options to change that behavior.

Comment: @tripleee The `\r\n` sequence is the standard line-ending in *Telnet* (it's not a Windows-specific thing in this case).

Comment: I add `\r` in function `broadcast`, now the result looks like:Hi, 
    ::ffff:127.0.0.1:51278!
                               ::ffff:127.0.0.1:51285: a
                                                        ::ffff:127.0.0.1:51285: b
                                                                                 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:51285: c

Comment: Technically, this is not telnet. You just have a TCP server, receiving TCP packages. There is nothing about it that makes this Telnet, you’re just using the telnet tool to connect to your raw TCP server.

Comment: @poke, I see. Then how should I address the problem to go by line instead of character per time?

Comment: You could write an actual telnet server in JavaScript, or [use an existing one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/telnet). Or to keep it super simple, just make your TCP server only respond to full lines. So you need to buffer incoming data until you hit a line break and then interpret every line separately.

Comment: @poke, thanks, I will try this way.